# Positioning span element doesn't change div width

Tags: css, html

I am creating a navigation bar that will display notifications much in the same way Facebook does (a little red circle with a number in it).

Using a `span` element to display the number of unread notifications it looks like this:

[image]

I then position it like so:

[image]

Of course positioning the `span` element like this leaves the space to the right that I would like to eliminate. How can this be achieved?

I think I could do it using JQuery to set the position of the `span` element to the same as the position of the bell icon (plus the offset) but there must be an easier way?

My navigation bar just contains `anchor` tags inside a `nav` tag. I am not using list elements.

Here is the notification link in my navigation bar:

```
  <a href="notifications.php"> 
        <i class="icon fa  fa-bell-o fa-lg"></i> <!-- bell icon -->
        <span><?php echo $num_notifications; ?></span> <!-- number -->
  </a>
```

And the CSS for the `span` element:

```
 position: relative;
 left: -14px;
 top: -8px;
```

Comment: u can just move the other icons by a -ve value

Comment: Or use position absolute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the position absolute. This will position it `relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static` [read more here.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Note you may need to apply some sort of positioning to the anchor tags in you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a matching negative right margin:

```
margin-right: -14px;
```